# Will doing 60,000 arm circles in a day cap your delts?

Tags: shoulders, upper-body-workout

I am really eager to know how to achieve those coconut shoulders! Could someone who has them that isn't a drug user please say how they got them?!

Comment: Holy smokes! 60,000 arm circles? Please, don't perform 60,000 reps of anything in a day. BTW, how's the rest of your body? Having awesome delts does nothing for you if the rest of your body don't go in sync. That being said, I've found ***crossover cable exercises*** to be very effective.

Comment: I suppose the swelling and disfigurement of your shoulder joint as it becomes permanently destroyed might make it look pretty big.

Comment: Train. Shoulders! Why in the world would you do arm circles and hope for muscle gains? What are all these questions about all the "alternative movements"? Why don't people want to go to the gym? Three sets of incline bench presses are going to do more than 100,000 arm circles. More good anyway. The arm circles might do more damage.

Comment: Please avoid asking the same question in different ways, both of which are duplicates of a previously asked question.

Comment: Are you kidding me?!

Answer (score 5):

If you're doing this, stop it immediately. You WILL hurt yourself.

Muscle gains are made by doing movements with physical resistance (weights). We need to break down the muscle fibers through intense exertion, and then our nutrition and rest make sure they're built back up, stronger and bigger.

Arm circles have no resistance besides air resistance, and the weight of your arm.

If you're doing more than 20 reps of anything, you're training stamina. Not muscle growth. So imagine what we're thinking when you say 60,000 reps. Do not do 60,000 reps of anything per day.

You have to also take into account that whenever you do a movement, there is mechanical damage being done to the joints. Three sets of 8-12 reps on the incline bench is going to give you more resistance than all of those arm circles, while at the same time not gnawing at your shoulder joints.

Comment: I would point out that physical resistance is not only limited to weights.

Answer (score 2):

Already been said but:

```
 1-8 Reps Strength Training

 9-12 Reps Hypertrophy Training <--- You want to be here...

 12-15 Reps Stamina Training`
```

Basically any kind of progression weight-wise using a hypertrophy rep range will gradually develop your shoulders to how you want them.

Shouldn't really have to do this for you (Should use your initiative)

However Here is a list of Shoulder exercices http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/finder/lookup/filter/muscle/id/12/muscle/shoulders

Answer (score 1):

NO. You need a lot more resistance to grow your delts, the kind of resistance that won't allow you to do 60k reps, or even 60.